# Concurrency violation - the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a VB.NET project and I am trying to Insert / Update some rows in the SQL DB.

To do this I use the code below to bring back a dataset based on 3 parameters.
If the dataset brings no data back, then the code simply inserts a new row.

This works fine.

However, if the data brings a row back (meaning the row already exists in the table) then I want to update one of the values instead.
This is where I'm getting the error in the title of this post.

Can anyone help me with where I'm going wrong please?

Thank you in advance.

```
Dim x_Update As Boolean

AdaptSql = New Data.AdapterX(SQL_ConnectionString)
DS = New DatsetX
AdaptSql.Fill(DS, Number, PeriodID, TypeID)

If DS.tbl_A.Count > 0 Then
    x_Row = DS.tbl_A(0)
    x_Row.BeginEdit()
    x_Update = True
Else
    x_Row = DS.tbl_A.NewRow
End If

x_Row.Number = Number
x_Row.DateID = PeriodID
x_Row.TypeID = TypeID
x_Row.Value = Value
x_Row.UpdatedDate = Date.Now

If x_Update = False Then DS.tbl_A.Addtbl_ARow(x_Row)

x_Row.EndEdit()

AdaptSql.Update(DS)

x_Row = Nothing
DS.Dispose()
AdaptSql = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

check the x_Row.RowState before call AdaptSql.Update(DS), for a newly created row, the row state should be "Added", while an existing record should have "Modified" since there was some updates to it.

Comment: Thank you for this - I've check the RowState as you say, and for the entry which goes in as a new row then the state is "Added" as expected. It is "Modified" for the row which is being updated.  I'm not fully sure what to do with this information now though?  I assume that the problem is occuring due to the fact that it is showing as "Modified"?

Comment: generally this kind of error is due to it failed to find a DB row when it tries to do update - it expects one row to be updated while find 0 based on the criteria constructed by the adaptor. Another try is to use sql profiler to monitor the sql text command sent from your code to SQL to do the update. and then examine the sql text command to see anything wrong\ and it could give some clues, but no guarantee.

Comment: another point i can think from the code: you updated the field [UpdateDate], did you check is there any trigger at table level to auto-update this field when any other field is updated? this could lead to the concurrency exception as well

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. It looks as though the problem might be due to the ID field in the table. This is an autonumbering identity field.  It's populating the dataset with the row it finds in the table, but when it's trying to update, could it be assigning it a different ID? If so, would you know how I would get around this?  I'm just checking this now.

Comment: i think you might need to re-visit the strong typed dataset and make some tinny changes to the guilty column to stop the dataset generate id for it, or at least, don't use this column in the where condition of the update command

Comment: Ok, I've just checked this and it's not doing what I thought. Basically for a new row, the dataset being updated has an ID of -1 and this works fine. For the updated row, the dataset being updated has the ID which was originally brought back into the dataset which is correct. I've no idea why it's not updating though, I'm just assuming it's to do with being an identity field.

Comment: have you checked the sql command generated by the dataset? query the db based on the condition to see whether you could find a record - i guess you could get a record, but when you do update, there is some field updated by triggers or so and then concurrency problem occurs